# How to run insalled electron app from web browser with a custom url protocol

Tags: javascript, electron, custom-protocol

I'm developing a electron app and I want to register my Electron app to open via custom url protocol. I need to register my application in registry in a button click event and need to open the app via registered protocol from a eb browser later. I saw that mailto: protocol is working correctly.